# Spring Framework - Mock is not mocking

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, junit, mockito

I have a Spring MvC app. (The Spring Framework is an application framework and inversion of control container for the Java platform) with this test:

```
    @RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
    public class AutorisationServiceTest {
    
        @Autowired
        @InjectMocks
        private IAutorisationService service;
    
        @Mock
        PersonneRepository personneRepository = Mockito.mock(PersonneRepository.class);
    
    
        @Before
        public void setup() {
        }
    
    
        @Test
        public void should_Find_GardeWith2Affectations() throws IOException {
    
            when(personneRepository.getAll(anyString())).thenReturn(DataLoader.mockData());
            service.getAll("rules");
        }
    
    }

    @Service
    public class AutorisationService implements IAutorisationService {
    
        private final PersonneRepository personneRepository;
    
        public AutorisationService(PersonneRepository personneRepository) {
            this.personneRepository = personneRepository;
        }

@Override
    public List<User> getAll(String where) {
        return personneRepository.getAll(where));
    }
    ...
    }
```

but when I run the test it seems no to mock the repo

Comment: Which junit you are using. Junit4 Or Junit5? Can you show the code with imports?

Comment: I am using 4.13

Comment: You are mocking a final object. Mocking the final object usually returns me null. Can you try changing it from final.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should decide whether you want to write a Spring test or a Mockito test.

A spring test will load the full context and you can then work with **@Autowired** and **@MockBean**:

```java
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
public class AutorisationServiceTest {
    
  @Autowired
  private IAutorisationService service;
    
  @MockBean
  PersonneRepository personneRepository;
```

A Mockito test runs much faster, but you will only have the objects you explicitly configured with **@InjectMocks** or **@Mock**:

```java
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class AutorisationServiceTest {
  
  @InjectMocks
  private IAutorisationService service;
    
  @Mock
  PersonneRepository personneRepository;
```

Note that you never have to instanciate the mock with Mockito.mock() when using annotations and specialized runners.

I guess your PersonneRepository is a @Service, @Component or @Repository. So you should use auto-wiring here as well:

```java
@Service
public class AutorisationService implements IAutorisationService {

   @Autowired    
   private PersonneRepository personneRepository;
```

Answer (score 1):

This answer is for **testng**:

`MockitoTestExecutionListener` initializes mocks, and you need to use `@MockBean` annotation.

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@TestExecutionListeners(MockitoTestExecutionListener.class)
public class AutorisationServiceTest {   
    @MockBean
    PersonneRepository personneRepository;
```

Also, don't forget to add `ResetMocksTestExecutionListener` to prevent inter-test persistent mocks (see this [issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/25366)).

Answer (score 0):

You can't use both `@Mock` and `Mockito.mock`.  Choose one of them

Comment: I removed Mockito.mock(PersonneRepository.class), but then I got a nullpointer

Comment: Can you initiate the service without the Autowire annotation?

Answer (score 0):

In @Before setup method you need to add MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this). This will inject your mocked services. I have modified the code below :

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
    public class AutorisationServiceTest {
    
        @Mock
        PersonneRepository personneRepository;

        @InjectMocks
        private AutorisationService service;
    
        @Before
        public void setup() {
          MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
        }
    
    
        @Test
        public void should_Find_GardeWith2Affectations() throws IOException {
    
            when(personneRepository.getAll(anyString())).thenReturn(DataLoader.mockData());
            service.getAll("rules");
        }
    
    }

    @Service
    public class AutorisationService implements IAutorisationService {
    
        private final PersonneRepository personneRepository;
    
        public AutorisationService(PersonneRepository personneRepository) {
            this.personneRepository = personneRepository;
        }

@Override
    public List<User> getAll(String where) {
        return personneRepository.getAll(where));
    }
    ...
    }
```